# Oracle: Alternative to sub-query

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there an alternative to re-write the below oracle query **without using sub-queries**

```
SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM TABLE WHERE COL2 IN (SELECT MAX(COL2) FROM TABLE)
```

**Edit**: There is only 1 table with COL1 and COL2 where the row with maximum value of 
      COL2 is the expected output

Comment: How come you're asking?

Comment: @jarlh Tried making the question more understandable now

Comment: Can there be two rows with the same col2 value or is col2 unique in the table?

Comment: All answers are good.. Please do take a  look at `FIRST`  and `LAST` aggregate function for another option.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT COL1,COL2 
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY COL2 DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

Answer (score 2):

This one should also work:

```
SELECT MAX(COL1) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY COL2) as COL1,
    MAX(COL2) as COL2 
FROM TABLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  PARTITION  key find out maximum col2 with col1 as per below:

```
select COL1, COL2 from (
select COL1, COL2, ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY COL1 ORDER BY COL2 desc) row_num  from TABLE 
 )  where row_num=1;
```

Comment: It is a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming COL1 can be used as candidate key -

```
SELECT T1.COL1,
  T1.COL2
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE1 T2
ON (T1.COL1  = T2.COL1
AND T1.COL2 >= T2.COL2)
```